# Importing JS function to another file

Tags: javascript, module, href

I'm trying to add an import to one of my JS files (both JS are in the same directory) but it seems to break with the following error:
"SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

```
<--HTML-->
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="my_link" onclick="run_my_function()"> click me </a>


<---main_file.js--->
import { new_func } from "./new_file.js";
function run_my_func(){
   ...
}

<---new_file.js--->
export { new_func };
function new_func(){
  ....
}
```

I tried to read other questions on this topic but couldn't find a proper solution.
I've tried also changing the ahref to script type="module" but it didn't work either.
any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
So I managed to fix it, and it might not be the best practice but it works for my scenario as I want to use a specific function is several JS files -

1. in the HTML script that loads the function I want to export (new_file.js) I added type="module".

```
 <script type="module" src="js/new_file.js"></script>
```

2. made new_func a global variable by adding it to window:

```
window.new_func = function() {
  ...
}
```

3. now I used new_func normally in every JS file that was imported after new_file

Comment: You need the `type="module"` on the _script tag_ that imports `main_file.js`, not on the link.

Comment: Also you are missing the closing quote for your `href` value.

Comment: is there any specific reason you are putting curly braces around new_func while exporting it ?`export { new_func }`

Comment: Not really, I'm pretty new to JS and saw some examples that use curly braces even when importing only 1 function @YogeshBhatt

Comment: @CherryDT adding type="module" to the script that imports the main_file.js is probably the right thing to do, but now it seems like the file was not loaded at all, I'm getting this error: "ReferenceError: run_my_func is not defined"

Comment: if you are using pure vanilla js, then would don't need to fiddle around with import / exports, they would be available to you during runtime, just call both of the scripts in the correct sequence and add the `<script>` tags for them

Comment: Are you adding the script with the import statement first in your html?

Comment: @LDevelop: probably because the function is defined _in the module_, not in global scope. You could add `globalThis.run_my_func = run_my_func` at the end of the module if you have to access it from global scope.